# How to extend template script?

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have the following template in my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
x-android-build-tools: &android_build_tools
  image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android
  stage: build
  script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hours
    paths:
      - app/build/
```

I want to extend the script part to make actual builds. For example:

```
android-stage-build:
  <<: *android_build_tools
  environment: stage
  only:
    - dev
  after_script:
    - ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug
```

It works well, but it has a problem. Docker launches the both jobs instead of ignoring the template.

Is there way to run **only** the "android-stage-build" job which triggers the template job when it will be needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make gitlab ci ignore the first entry, you need to add a dot (`.`) in front of the definition.

```yaml
.x-android-build-tools: &android_build_tools
  image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android
  stage: build
  script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hours
    paths:
      - app/build/

android-stage-build:
  <<: *android_build_tools
  environment: stage
  only:
    - dev
  after_script:
    - ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug
```

Besides that, I think, based on what I read here, you don't want to use `after_script`.

I think you want to use the `before_script` in the template, and on the build stage specific the `script`-key.
The main difference is that [after_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#after_script) also runs if the script fails. And by what I read here, it does not look like you would like that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You're simply missing a `.` :)

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors

It should work if you write it like this:

```yaml
.x-android-build-tools: &android_build_tools
  image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android
  stage: build
  script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hours
    paths:
      - app/build/

android-stage-build:
  <<: *android_build_tools
  environment: stage
  only:
    - dev
  after_script:
    - ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug
```